# assetic.ERROR "DoctrineBundle:Collector:db.html.twig" contains an error: Unknown "profiler_dump" function

Tags: symfony, assetic, symfony-3.1

I am trying to send emails with Symfony. Everything works perfect locally. But on server I get following errore in `prod.log`:

`assetic.ERROR: The template "SecurityBundle:Collector:security.html.twig" contains an error: Unknown "profiler_dump" function in "SecurityBundle:Collector:security.html.twig" at line 180.`

`assetic.ERROR: The template "DoctrineBundle:Collector:db.html.twig" contains an error: Unknown "profiler_dump" function in "DoctrineBundle:Collector:db.html.twig" at line 241`

These are bundles I have in composer.json

```
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.1.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "3.0.1",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "justinrainbow/json-schema": "~2.0",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "1.1.0",
    "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "1.6.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.2",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^2.5",
    "mapado/mysql-doctrine-functions": "1.*",
    "hampe/zurb-ink-bundle": "^2.2",
```

This are bundles in AppKernel class

```
  $bundles = [
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        new AdminBundle\AdminBundle(),
        new APIBundle\APIBundle(),
        new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle(),
        new Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),
        new NotificationBundle\NotificationBundle(),
        new Hampe\Bundle\ZurbInkBundle\HampeZurbInkBundle(),
    ];
```

Comment: can you share your `AppKernel` class?

Comment: @Matteo ok, added

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, AsseticBundle will try to handle the templates of all enabled bundles which leads to errors when enabled bundles ship with templates that rely on features not being loaded in the `prod` environment. You can solve your issue by explicitly listing all bundles that should be handled by Assetic using the [`assetic.bundles` option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/assetic.html).

Comment: Is this is possibly a bug in Doctrine?

Comment: No, DoctrineBundle does not use this template in the `prod` environment (to be clear it's the profiler that is not used here and thus not rendering this template).

Comment: The problem is the template exists in a bundle that is included in prod. So assetic will try to process it regardless of whether it's used.

Comment: The only working link is this: https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/reference/configuration/assetic.html you can also try `php bin/console debug:config assetic` to see current settings

Answer (score 1):

`profiler_dump` method comes from Symfony's WebProfilerBundle.
This bundle is not applied to Kernel in production mode, and it should not be (WebProfiler toolbar should be enabled only during development). You should remove those calls from twig template.

Comment: This template is part of the doctrine bundle so can't be removed so easily.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by creating twig extension defining empty function `profiler_dump` and loading this twig extension only in production.